# ASP.NET first time using createuserwizard component

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2005

I am new in ASP 2.0 and i need help to create a createUserWizard. It is not for a real application, it is just for homework. Could someone give me some guidelines on what should i do?

This is what i did so far:

1-I created the database with a user table
[image]

2-I create a page for registration and i added the userWizardComponent on it:

[image]

What should i do now to be able to:

-Add users to the database

-Make the password validation less restrictive(I cannot enter it correctly i would like to make it easier or dissable it).

Ill appreciate your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is homework, I'll just try and give you some guidance in the right direction.

Firstly, the create user wizard is designed to work against ASP.NET's built in Membership api. This api utilizes a certain Database schema which can be automatically created in a database using the "aspnet_regsql" tool. For more information on ASP.NET Membership, check out these links: [Introduction to Membership](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy.aspx) and [Walkthrough: Creating a Web Site with membership and login](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/879kf95c.aspx)

That should get you started in the right direction. To relax the constraints on the password, you would modify the membership settings in web.config and the above links should also point that out. You can control the minimum length, number of special characters, etc.

Comment: In the Prerequisites says: Visual studio 2010.
I use 2005 do you think i will be ok?

Comment: It should be very similar and still work, yes, but you can switch to a vs2005 specific version of both of those links by clicking on the "other versions" drop down just under the title at the top of the page and selecting "Visual Studio 2005". You could also always download VS2010 express for free from Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run `AspNet_regsql` from the VS Tools Command Prompt to create the tables used by the ASP.Net membership system.

You can change the complexity requirements [in Web.config](http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2005/05/11/406550.aspx).

Comment: Could you explain me how can i run VS Tools from Command? I never did that before.

Comment: You'll find it in the Start menu.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET has a built in Membership system that those controls work with.  You do not need to create a custom database to store user information (unless of course it is a requirement of your assignment).  Rather, run the AspNet_regsql tool from the VS command prompt which will create the Membership database.

In order to make less restrictive passwords and things like that, you'll need to research custom Membership Providers, and this is set in the web.config.

Comment: You mean i don't need the database i created above? Users will register automatically when i create them? Also i wanted to ask you one more thing. My project does not have a web.config file. Could you explain me how can i create one and what should i add to it?

Comment: When you run the tool the tool will create quite a few databases, stored procedures, and Views that will be used by the membership provider in asp.net.

Comment: @sfrj, No you do not need to create the "Database.mdf" that you created above.  First, you need to either run AspNet_regsql from the VS command prompt or click "Websites > Asp.net Configuration" from the top menu to go through the wizard to set up membership. This will create the membership database for you.  The createuserwizard control will then interface with that database. (The database it creates for you is usually called ASPNETDB and will be placed in your App_Data folder.